# How to get the TestContext From TestRunner?

Tags: cucumber, citrus-framework

How can I get the TestContext from the TestRunner?

I am doing cucumber citrus integration. in my step I use

```
@CitrusResource
private TestRunner          runner;
```

to get the runner no issue. but for:

```
@CitrusResource
private TestContext         testContext;
```

it always returns null. I am sure all my properties setup is correct, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The TestContext injection is only available on method level.

E.g.

```
public class ResourceInjectionIT extends JUnit4CitrusTestDesigner {

  @Test
  @CitrusTest
  public void resourceInjectionIT(@CitrusResource TestContext context) {
      context.setVariable("myVariable", "some value");
      echo("${myVariable}");
  }
}
```

For more details, please have a look into the documentation for [Test Context injection](http://citrusframework.org/citrus/reference/html/index.html#test-context-injection)

Answer (score 1):

you could cast the `TestRunner` to `DefaultTestRunner` which provides a method `getTestContext()` that returns the TestContext.

```
@CitrusResource
private TestRunner runner;

@Test
@CitrusTest
public void fooIT() {
    TestContext context = ((DefaultTestRunner) runner).getTestContext();

    // do whatever you want with the context
}
```